# taffy using customserializer

Tags: coldfusion, lucee, taffy

i can find how the custom serializer is used in taffy,

i have one CFC named as `contact.cfc` which is extending `taffy.core.resource` and the `resource.cf`c does not have `getasjson` method nor it is extending any component.

i declared ii application as:

```
variables.framework.serializer = "resources/customerserialier";
```

so how will I use the `getasjson` method in custom serializer in `contact.cfc` because nothing is extending nothing here